# Crontab: Ubuntu running script (noob)

Tags: bash, scripts, cron

I'm new to crontab and would like to run the following script from `/etc/crontab`:

```
0 15    * * *   root    bash-c 'for i in /home/dell/Downloads/*.{pdf,docx,png,jpg,PDF,DOCX}; do shred -zvu "$i" -n20; done'
```

I have tried with and without `bash-c` option, yet the script doesn't run.

My objective is:

1. Get this script running from Crontab
2. Get this script running on startup

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Consider putting this in your user crontab (i.e. `crontab -e` as user `dell`) instead of in the system crontab as root.

Comment: Thanks for all comments. 
Executing the command in a script and adding this all to crontab -e, instead of trying to modify /etc/crontab seems to resolve the issues.
One question remains:
Running -> 31 15   * * *           /home/dell/shred.sh -> works.
Running -> @reboot               /home/dell/shred.sh -> does not work.
One of my main frustrations here is that there are no error messages,  no indication what is done incorrectly. Appreciate your input how I can run this script on startup.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're missing a space after the command `bash` and the argument `-c`.

This should work:

```
0 15    * * *  root bash -c 'for i in /home/dell/Downloads/*.{pdf,docx,png,jpg,PDF,DOCX}; do shred -zvu "$i" -n20; done'
```

---

**Some additional hints:**

- Don't run a `crontab` as user `root` if you don't need to.
- You wrote that you put it in `/etc/crontab` file. **[Don't edit crontab files directly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/609850/what-is-the-correct-way-to-edit-a-crontab-file)**, rather use `crontab -e` command or `sudo crontab -e` for commands which need `root` rights. Note, that you don't put the `user` field in the "other" `crontab` files.
- If you have more than one command you can use `bash -c` as you do, but I'd rather [put the commands in a script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223691/how-do-i-create-a-script-file-for-terminal-commands) and execute this from crontab.
- To run a script on startup, you can use `@reboot` instead of `0 15 * * *`.

Comment: _“I'm not sure what the word root is about here.”_ See the header of `/etc/crontab`: _Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab` command to install the new version when you edit this file
and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also **have username fields**,
that none of the other crontabs do._ However, in this case, only the user’s home folder is involved, so `root` should be not used in this case.

Comment: thanks, as I never edited `/etc/crontab` directly I didn't even know this... :-D

Comment: See also [Two Other Types of Crontab](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto#Two_Other_Types_of_Crontab)

Comment: I suspect there may be a more fundamental issue with running a `bash -c` command from cron, since IIRC each command is implicitly executed by `/bin/sh -c` (or, more exactly, `$SHELL -c`). It *may* be necessary to set `SHELL=/bin/bash` (to suport brace expansion etc.) and then run the command *without* the `bash -c` wrapper. But really the best approach (as you note) is to put the bash code in an external script file.