# Create a Cron File on Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, cron

I am trying to create a .txt file via Cron in Ubuntu, but I have no error errors nor is the file created. I am editing or archiving the file inside / etc with the following **command** line:

'* * * * * cd /home/appi9-02/Documentos && touch newFile.txt'

**I already tried:**

'* * * * * cd /home/appi9-02/Documentos && touch newFile.txt'

After editing I save and restart cron with the following command: sudo service cron restart.

A lot of time goes by and the file is not created.

Comment: We labour under the handicap of understanding only English. Please post in English. You can also find the community support channel on Freenode IRC server: #Ubuntu-es

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Please [edit] your question to specify what file you are editing. Restarting cron service is definitely not necessary, it automatically reads current configuration when it’s triggered.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I managed to solve in the right place. I was editing the file / etc / crontab. This is Linux itself but with the command crontab -e, has crontab for my edit. I added what I needed to this file and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the correct way to edit a crontab file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/609850/what-is-the-correct-way-to-edit-a-crontab-file)